# Replicate C# code hash to PHP

Tags: c#, php, hash

I have to replicate C# hash from the code below into PHP. I have been searching but didn't find a solution so far.

```cs
private string createHash(string stringToHash)
    {
        // Byte[] originalBytes;

        MD5 hash = MD5.Create();

        hash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

        // originalBytes = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(stringToHash);

        byte[] data = hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(stringToHash));

        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {

            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));

        }

        return sBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Thanx for you help!

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Atleast show what is the input and output of the above code.

Comment: The creator of MD5 announced last year that it's no longer secure: http://www.zdnet.com/blog/security/md5-password-scrambler-no-longer-safe/12317. Recommend that you use `bcrypt` instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php

Comment: This is example app for PayEx service write on C#.

Comment: Do you want to understand what this code is doing, so you can translate it to PHP (hint: it's one function, whose name is three characters long) or do you just want someone to give you the code?

Answer (score 1):

PHP has an in-built function - [MD5](http://www.php.net/md5)

```
<?php
    $hash = md5("plain text");
    echo $hash;
?>
```